# Why rttest allocates 8GB of memory?

Tags: ros, ros2, real-time, memory

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i'm going thru rttest ulitity and was wondering why "lock_and_prefault_dynamic()" always locks 8GB of heap memory?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Build as described in [README.md](https://github.com/ros2/realtime_support/tree/master/rttest)
2. Set unlimited memlock `user           -       memlock         -1` in `/etc/security/limits.conf`, relogin
3. Run `./example_loop -i 10000`
4. In separate terminal check memory usage by `top` (RES column)

8GB also mentioned in [Real-Time-Programming](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Real-Time-Programming/)

From what i understand `lock_and_prefault_dynamic()` sets allocation options (no trim, no mmap) and then allocates memory in 64*4k chunks until allocation hits NO page faults. The question is why it's always 8GB?

I'm testing on NVIDIA Jetson AGX Xavier which has 16GB ram.

EDIT:

also checked on google cloud VM with 32GB of total ram (no swap). Getting same number 8GB

My Xavier `ulimit -a`

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 62481
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 81920
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 62481
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337066/why-rttest-allocates-8gb-of-memory?/) by [r7vme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39591/r7vme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2019-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to @sgermanserrano for pointing out to his workaround on how to decrease memory usage this gave me a first clue on what's going on.

#### What happens in `lock_and_prefault_dynamic` function?

On every iteration `262144` bytes  (`64 * page_size`) allocated on the heap memory by new char array. Also there is a `std::vector` which holds pointers to allocated arrays. So on every iteration this vector increased by `8` bytes (size of 64 bit pointer). As soon as vector needs to be resized, it reallocated 2x new heap memory, copies data there and deallocates old memory (see details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17302443/5341695)).

This means that heap memory fragmented with chunks of free memory from vector reallocations. And as soon as there will be available free chunk of size `262144` bytes it will be used for new char array and **no minor page fault** will happen, which will meet while loop condition.

#### Why 8GB?

In order to reach size of `262144` bytes vector needs `262144 / 8 = 32768` elements, which is `32768` iterations, which is `32768` of char arrays of size  `64 * 4 * 1024` totals into `8589934592 bytes` (8GB). Plus memory from reallocated vector data, which is not so significant (actually two char arrays - `512`KB).

#### Code

I did a small patch with debug logging, which shows the following

```
DEBUG: Memory chunk required 262144
DEBUG: Heap memory chunk of size 8 will be available between 0x55599f4fe0 - 0x55599f4fe0.
DEBUG: Heap memory chunk of size 16 will be available between 0x5559a7b220 - 0x5559a7b228.
DEBUG: Heap memory chunk of size 32 will be available between 0x5559abb250 - 0x5559abb268.
DEBUG: Heap memory chunk of size 64 will be available between 0x5559b3b2a0 - 0x5559b3b2d8.
DEBUG: Heap memory chunk of size 128 will be available between 0x5559c3b330 - 0x5559c3b3a8.
DEBUG: Heap memory chunk of size 256 will be available between 0x5559e3b440 - 0x5559e3b538.
DEBUG: Heap memory chunk of size 512 will be available between 0x555a23b650 - 0x555a23b848.
DEBUG: Heap memory chunk of size 1024 will be available between 0x555aa3ba60 - 0x555aa3be58.
DEBUG: Heap memory chunk of size 2048 will be available between 0x555ba3c270 - 0x555ba3ca68.
DEBUG: Heap memory chunk of size 4096 will be available between 0x555da3d280 - 0x555da3e278.
DEBUG: Heap memory chunk of size 8192 will be available between 0x5561a3f290 - 0x5561a41288.
DEBUG: Heap memory chunk of size 16384 will be available between 0x5569a432a0 - 0x5569a47298.
DEBUG: Heap memory chunk of size 32768 will be available between 0x5579a4b2b0 - 0x5579a532a8.
DEBUG: Heap memory chunk of size 65536 will be available between 0x5599a5b2c0 - 0x5599a6b2b8.
DEBUG: Heap memory chunk of size 131072 will be available between 0x55d9a7b2d0 - 0x55d9a9b2c8.
DEBUG: Heap memory chunk of size 262144 will be available between 0x5659abb2e0 - 0x5659afb2d8.
DEBUG: New char array address 0x5659abb2e0 is lower the old one 0x5759b7b2f0.
DEBUG: This means it was created in already allocated memory.
```

Patch

```
diff --git a/rttest/src/rttest.cpp b/rttest/src/rttest.cpp
index cb21d13..6d78bfb 100644
--- a/rttest/src/rttest.cpp
+++ b/rttest/src/rttest.cpp
@@ -676,6 +676,8 @@ int Rttest::lock_and_prefault_dynamic()
   size_t prev_majflts = usage.ru_majflt;
   size_t encountered_minflts = 1;
   size_t encountered_majflts = 1;
+
+  printf("DEBUG: Memory chunk required %zu\n", (64 * page_size));
   // prefault until you see no more pagefaults
   while (encountered_minflts > 0 || encountered_majflts > 0) {
     char * ptr;
@@ -694,6 +696,22 @@ int Rttest::lock_and_prefault_dynamic()
       munlockall();
       return -1;
     }
+
+    if (&prefaulter.front() != nullptr)
+    {
+      if (prefaulter.size() == prefaulter.capacity())
+      {
+        long int v_size = ((&prefaulter.back() - &prefaulter.front()) + 1) * sizeof(void*);
+        printf("DEBUG: Heap memory chunk of size %ld will be available between %p - %p.\n", v_size, &prefaulter.front(), &prefaulter.back());
+      }
+
+      if ((ptr - prefaulter.back()) < 0)
+      {
+        printf("DEBUG: New char array address %p is lower the old one %p.\n", ptr, &prefaulter.back());
+        printf("DEBUG: This means it was created in already allocated memory.\n");
+      }
+    }
+
     prefaulter.push_back(ptr);
     getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
     size_t current_minflt = usage.ru_minflt;
```

---

Originally posted by [r7vme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39591/r7vme/) with karma: 286 on 2019-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [r7vme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39591/r7vme/) on 2019-11-22**:
Created github issue https://github.com/ros2/realtime_support/issues/87